# Best way to wait for asynchronous initialization from a module import?

Tags: node.js, asynchronous, promise, synchronous, discord

TL;DR: is there a way to wait for a module import with async functionality to complete before continuing with execution in the calling module in order to keep module functionality contained?

I'm working on a personal node project that I've been structuring in a modular/OOP way as the codebase has continued to grow. One requirement has been to enable logging across modules / objects, where different logfiles can be logged to at different times. I thought that I had solved the problem in a pretty clean way by creating a Logger.js file with an init function that I could use at any time by simply importing the Logger.js file in any module that I needed. Here is the stripped down code to illustrate this:

Logger.js

```
module.exports.init = function(location) {
    var logFileBaseName = basePath + fullDatePathName;
    var studentLogFile = fs.createWriteStream(logFileBaseName + '-student.log', {flags : 'a'});
    var teacherLogFile = fs.createWriteStream(logFileBaseName + '-teacher.log', {flags : 'a'});

    this.studentLog = function () {
        arguments[0] = '[' + Utils.getFullDate() + '] ' + arguments[0].toString();
        studentLogFile.write(util.format.apply(null, arguments) + '\n');
    }
    this.teacherBookLog = function () {
        arguments[0] = '[' + Utils.getFullDate() + '] ' + arguments[0].toString();
        teacherLogFile.write(util.format.apply(null, arguments) + '\n');
    }
}
```

This seemed great, because in my main entrypoint I could simply do:

Main.js

```
const Logger = require('./utils/Logger');

Logger.init(path);
Logger.studentLog('test from Main');

// all my other code and more logging here
```

And in my other dozens of files I could do even less:

AnotherFile.js

```
const Logger = require('./utils/Logger');

Logger.studentLog('test from AnotherFile')
```

Then the requirement came to log not only to a file for the 'student logs', but to Discord (a chat client) as well. Seemed easy, I had this Logger file and I could just initialize Discord and log to Discord alongside the 'student logs', something like this:

Logger.js

```
module.exports.init = function(location) {

    // code we've already seen above

    var client = new Discord.Client();
    client.login('my_login_string');
    channels = client.channels;

    this.studentLog = function () {
        arguments[0] = '[' + Utils.getFullDate() + '] ' + arguments[0].toString();
        var message = util.format.apply(null, arguments) + '\n';
        studentLogFile.write(message);
        channels.get('the_channel_to_log_to').send(message)
    }

    // more code we've already seen above
}
```

The problem is that if you were to re-run Main.js again, the studentLog would fail because the .login() function is asynchronous, it returns a Promise. The login has not completed and channels would be an empty Collection by the time we try to call `Logger.studentLog('test from Main');`

I've tried using a Promise in Logger.js, but of course execution of Main.js continues before the promise returns in Logger.js. I would love it if Main.js could simply wait until the Discord login was complete.

My question is, what is the best way to make this work while keeping with the pattern I've been using? I know that I could wrap my entire main function in a promise.then() that waits for Discord login to complete, but that seems a bit absurd to me. I'm trying to keep functionality contained into modules and would not like for this kind of Logger code / logic to spill out into my other modules. I want to keep it to a simple Logger import as I've been doing.

Any advice would be great!!

Comment: You don't want to wrap the client login in logger.js in `.then`? That is, `client.login(token).then(success=>{//everything else});` because that seems the simplest.

Comment: Embrace the asynchronous pattern, and give up on synchronous patterns. You'll live happy ever after.

Comment: @Wright I did try wrapping it with a .then() in the Logger. The problem is that main still continues before the Logger reaches the .then(), meaning it attempts to use Discord client before it is fully initialized.

Comment: @trincot The goal is definitely to embrace the asynchronous pattern, but how? Do you suggest just giving up on keeping all Logger logic contained to Logger.js and wrapping all of my Main.js code with a promise that waits for Discord's login() function to return?

Comment: You definitely need to put all code that depends on the async result in a callback (a `then` callback for promises) or in an `async/await` construct: both involve a function wrapper. Of course, you can call other functions from within such a callback.

Comment: @trincot thanks for the help, I was hoping to avoid wrapping all of my code in a callback just to wait for discord, but it sounds like that's the best approach. I'll try to make it look pretty!

Answer (score 0):

If the result of some async function is awaited and then used in the same caller function, the result is resolved first, then used. If the result is used in another function or module (e.g. the result is assigned to a global variable), it is not resolved. In your case, if `client.login()` assigns a value to `client.channels` asynchronously, that assignment is **not** awaited, and `channels = client.channels` assignment will assign `undefined` to `channels`.

To resolve this issue, you must use a callback or return a promise from `client.login()`, as stated in the comments.

You can refer to [this](https://bytearcher.com/articles/asynchronous-call-in-constructor/) article.

Answer (score 0):

Let me offer my solution to the **"asynchronously initialised logger"** problem. Note that this only deals with logging and most likely cannot be generalised.

Basically, all messages are appended to a *queue* that is only sent to the remote location once a flag inidicating that the connection is ready is set.

Example:

```js
//Logger.js
module.exports = {
  _ready: false,
  _queue: [],

  init(): {
    return connectToRemote().then(()=>{this._ready = true})
  },

  log(message): {
    console.log(message);
    _queue.push(message)
    if (this._ready) {
      let messagesToSend = this._queue;
      this._queue = [];
      this._ready = false;
      sendToRemote(messagesToSend).then(()=>this._ready = true);
    }
  }

}
```

You can require the logger in any file and use the log funciton right away. The logs will be sent only after the init funciton that you can call anytime is resolved.

This is a very bare bones example, you may also want to limit the queue size and/or only send the logs in bulk in certain time intervals, but you get the idea.